# c# помогите с Regex

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

нужно из текста выделить такую строку:

`<coverpage><image l:href="#cover.jpg"/></coverpage>`

составил регэксп `@"<coverpage><image l:href=""#(.*?)""/></coverpage>"`
совпадений нет
проверил на сайте https://regex101.com/r/zcTpqR/2
работает, правда вот такой \" вариант кавычек, а в проге не работает
`"<coverpage><image l:href=\"#(.*?)\"/></coverpage>"`

**UPD:**

```
xdoc = new XDocument();
xdoc = XDocument.Load(opf.FileName);

string xdocstr = xdoc.ToString();
string t1 = Regex.Replace(xdocstr, @"<FictionBook[^>]*>", "<FictionBook>");//убираю неймспейсы потому что уже голова болит от возни с ними

MatchCollection mcol = Regex.Matches(t1, @"<coverpage><image l:href=""#(.*?)""/></coverpage>");

string coverStr = "";
foreach (Match m in mcol)
{
    coverStr += m.Groups[1].Value + "\n";//строка пустая
}
```

Весь текст книги не буду выкладывать, он большой. Если пригодится то вот полный файл https://yadi.sk/d/NKpYCB4UoZlXLw

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FictionBook xmlns="http://www.gribuser.ru/xml/fictionbook/2.0" xmlns:l="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <description>
        <title-info>
            <genre>sf</genre>
            <author>
                <first-name>Айзек</first-name>
                <last-name>Азимов</last-name>
            </author>
            <book-title>Профессия</book-title>
            <annotation>
                <i>
                На Земле, по прошествии 4-5 тысяч лет система образования, естественно, претерпела массу изменений и нововедений. В восемь лет все дети должны были пройти День Чтения, когда соответствующая программа с ленты, обучающей чтению, за 15 минут переписывалась в мозг ребенка. В 18 лет на Дне Знаний компьютер выбирал для человека его оптимальную профессию и закладывал в его мозг соответствующую программу. Затем каждый год проводились Олимпиады, где планеты, требующие специалистов, отбирали себе лучших.

                Джордж Пленетей страстно хотел стать программистом и тайком от всех изучал книги по програмированию. Но в 18 лет в День знаний компьютер выбрал ему совсем другую специальность.
                </i>
            </annotation>
            <date>1957</date>
            <1--  вот это нужно достать -->
            <coverpage><image l:href="#cover.jpg"/></coverpage>
            <lang>ru</lang>
            <src-lang>en</src-lang>
            <translator>
                <first-name>Светлана</first-name>
                <last-name>Васильева</last-name>
            </translator>
            <sequence number='0' name='Шедевры фантастики'/>
        </title-info>
```

Comment: 1. Для разбора HTML лучше использовать HTML-парсеры. 2. Диалект .NET-регулярок лучше проверять здесь: http://regexstorm.net/tester. 3. Ваша регулярка не учитывает возможные незначащие пробелы, приведите фрагмент входного HTML дословно

Comment: @АндрейNOP а если по теме вопроса? мне нужна именно регулярка.  пробелов в строке нет. приведенный сайт дает такой же результат. фрагмент приведен дословно

Comment: А если по теме, то у меня проблема не воспроизводится: https://ideone.com/oC9nZk

Comment: А покажите весь код, как вы используете Regex. У меня ваш регулярка находит совпадение.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov добавил

Comment: `xdoc.ToString()` - здесь вы получаете отформатированный xml с пробелами.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov OMG. Спасибо. заработало. Добавил \s*

Comment: Зачем вам регулярки, если вы используете `XDocument` - делайте всё с его помощью. Или совсем уберите его, читайте текст `string xdocstr = File.ReadAllText(opf.FileName);`

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov применил такой кривой метод потому что  
в корневом элменете есть неймспейс. при выборке XDocument не находит узлы.
без неймспейса находит. не смог с этим разобраться и решил убрать его регуляркой. как сделать выборку не трогая неймспейс?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96454/discussion-between-axmed2004-and-alexander-petrov).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод `XDocument.ToString` возвращает *форматированный* xml с пробельными символами. Поэтому ваша регулярка ничего не находит.

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
string xdocstr = xdoc.ToString(); // здесь получаем форматированный xml
```

Вы уже сами нашли решение: добавить в шаблон пробелы `\s*`.

---

Если вы используете регулярные выражения, то `XDocument` вас не нужен. Можете полностью убрать его использование из кода.

Просто читайте из файла текст и работайте с ним.

```
var xml = File.ReadAllText(opf.FileName);

var pattern = @"<coverpage><image l:href=""#(.*?)""/></coverpage>";

var matches = Regex.Matches(xml, pattern);
```

Хотя и в этом случае следует учитывать пробельные символы. По стандарту они могут присутствовать в xml в любом месте с любом количестве. То есть они могут быть в самом файле изначально.

---

Но гораздо правильней работать с fb2 с помощью xml-парсеров. Регулярки при этом совершенно не нужны.

Достаточно определить имеющиеся в этом формате пространства имён и далее использовать их.

```
XNamespace fb = "http://www.gribuser.ru/xml/fictionbook/2.0";
XNamespace link = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink";

var xdoc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");

var images = xdoc.Descendants(fb + "coverpage").Elements(fb + "image");

string coverStr = null;
foreach (var image in images)
{
    Console.WriteLine(image.Attribute(link + "href").Value);
    coverStr += image.Attribute(link + "href").Value;
}
```

Обратите внимание: я просто присоединяю неймспейс к имени элемента: `fb + "coverpage"`. Аналогично поступаем с атрибутом.

Comment: А вдруг неймспейс будет другой? Как выдернуть его?

Comment: @axmed2004 - откуда там возьмутся другие? Формат fb2 задан спецификацией. В ней указаны все используемые пространства имён.

Comment: спасибо. все заработало